# Can't make ob_get_clean() string into an integer, says output is an 18-character string

Tags: php, integer, output-buffering

I am trying to obtain a number from a function which only echos text instead of returning it to a variable as follows:

```
ob_start();
function_to_get_id_number();
$thisIDnumber = ob_get_clean();
```

If I echo the `$thisIDnumber` variable, the desired number is printed in the HTML output.

However, running `var_dump($thisIDnumber)` outputs the following: **string(18) "7"**
(Assuming the number was 7, although var_dump() reports an 18-character string regardless of what the number might be.)

Any attempt to convert the string to an integer (e.g. `(int)$thisIDnumber` , or `int_val($thisIDnumber)`, or `$thisIDnumber = 0+$thisIDnumber` fails and the output is 0)

Running `mb_detect_encoding($thisIDnumber)` reports the string to be ASCII encoded.

I'm not really sure how to get around this, but would very greatly appreciate any suggestions or insights! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What all does `function_to_get_id_number()` output? Are there any new lines that might be getting output unintentionally?

Comment: Outputting `$thisIDnumber` using `nl2br()` doesn't insert any `<BR />` tags, and using `print_r()` inside of a `<!-- Comment Block -->` also doesn't show any extra whitespace or newslines.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does `function_to_get_id_number()` have to echo instead of return?

Answer (score 1):

The `string(18)` part could be explained if the function prints lots of white space (spaces, tabs or even carriage returns) and you inspect var_dump()'s output through a web browser (so it renders as HTML and spaces are collapsed). However, casting to number should ignore regular leading spaces. So there's possibly some other non-printable character out there.

Try this:

```
ob_start();
function_to_get_id_number();
$thisIDnumber = ob_get_clean();

var_dump($thisIDnumber, bin2hex($thisIDnumber));
```

The hexadecimal code should give you a clue of what's inside the string.

**Update:**

```
$data = '5b777073635f63617465676f72795f69645d';

for($i=0, $len=strlen($data); $i<$len; $i+=2){
    echo chr(hexdec(substr($data, $i, 2)));
}
```

... prints this:

```
[wpsc_category_id]
```

:-?

Comment: I've attempted the `var_dump($thisIDnumber, bin2hex($thisIDnumber));` as you've suggested, and HTML prints the following:

`string(18) “7″ string(36) “5b777073635f63617465676f72795f69645d”`

I've tried using `trim($thisIDnumber)` and `preg_replace("/[\n\r]/","",$thisIDnumber)` on the string to remove any new lines or whitespace, neither of which have any effect.

Outputing to HTML using `nl2br()` also doesn't insert an <BR /> tags, so I'm not sure whitespace or new lines are the issue.

Any other suggestions? Appreciate your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided much information to work with, so this is a shot in the dark.

Why don't you try this:
If the id is numeric by definition, enforce it by removing everything else using a regular expression.

(As jproffit wrote in his comment to your question: more info on `function_to_get_id_number()` would be nice. Why do you need to buffer the output in the first place? Can't `function_to_...` return a proper value instead of outputting a string?)